# Game speed sometimes too slow, how to make it dynamic based on machine

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

how to make phaser game work faster with slow CPU machines, the speed is done like this at the moment.  Speed variable (gas) changes between 100-300 in game  and with good CPU car is moving well.

> `this.sprite.body.angularVelocity = -8 * (this.speed / 1000) }`

Comment: I don't see how your in-game car speed is related to your machine's performances tho. If your PC can't run a phaser game it's either because you should really improve your game's memory and CPU usage, or simply because your pc is a potatoe.

Comment: You need a dynamic framerate so you can calculate speed (not your speed variable but a global speed adjustment for the game) on the fly based on performance

Comment: For some reason the 3rd party dynamic html5 banner game ads are slowing down my game too much in older machines.